# Line integral vector field in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need help for this excercise:

The vectorfield $F(x,y) = (xy,0,0)^T$ is given.

$C_i$ is one of the bows of the curve $r(x,y) = a$ which connects the points $A(1;0;0)$ and $B(0;1;0)$.

Calculate the values of the line integral along the ways which connect $A$ and $B$.

What does $r(x,y) = a$ exactly mean? Is it just an arbitrary implicit function?

How should I start solving this exercise?

Comment: $a$ is probably some constant, in which case the curve $r(x,y)=a$ is a [level set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set) or curve. Seeing as you are not given any specific info about this curve, you are probably supposed to apply the gradient theorem to compute the integral. So the first step would be to show that $F(x,y)$ is the gradient of some scalar function $f(x,y)$.

Comment: The language is a bit confusing, but I think the idea is for you to parameterize the curve joining (1,0,0) to (0,1,0) and integrate along this line, then apply gradient theorem.

Comment: @user170231 - alas, $F$ is not the gradient of any function (even ignoring the 2D -> 3D problem, since $z$ is always 0). @ Niklas - Is there any additional information accompaning the problem? Say, a diagram, or maybe related problems or context that offer some definition for $r$?

Comment: @Enforce - how would you recommend Niklas parametrize a curve they know nothing about except the endpoints?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I meant the straight line. Poor terminology.

Comment: @PaulSinclair No, that is the whole excercise. No graph or any additional information. My guess was that a quarter circle in the first quadrant is meant. So I have to integrate from 0 to PI/2 in polar coordinates. The excercise is originally in german and I've just transtlate it. I guess it should be called "arc" instead of "bow". I'm sorry.

Comment: If it were not for the mixing of two and three dimensions, I would say you were right - that $r(x,y)$ is the just the author's non-standard notation for the distance from $(x,y)$ to the origin (commonly denoted by $\|(x,y)\|$ or just $|(x,y)|$. But if that were the case, then $C_i$ would be a circle arc in $\Bbb R^2$, while the points $A, B$ it is supposed to connect are in $\Bbb R^3$. In fact, I find the whole "let's bring in a third dimension, but make it all zero" concept in this question quixotic at best.